# VB.NET create (MS ACCESS like) "linked forms"

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, filter

NET (basic) I have on form1 a DGV1 displaying customer names (Dataset from SQL Database). I want to double-click on "a" customer name in DGV1, form1 and then see "Customer Details" in DGV2, form2.

I can make that on one form, easy DGV1 and DGV2 when select customer name in top DGV then bottom DGV updates accordingly. I want this on two forms as above explain.

Thanks,
Michelle

Comment: Are you asking how to open a new form when you click a line on the grid?

Comment: Hello Steve, No, I can open a new form from the DGV click.. If I click on a line in grid e.g. customer name "John" then I want form2 must open AND display details for JOHN in DGV2 .e.g age, gender, phone.. So I can make DGV but at moment show ALL details of ALL customers.. Because I select JOHN in form1,  I only want see John details in form2..

Comment: Your second form should receive the details of the customer line clicked. How do you do this depends on how you have initialized your first grid. (Do you use a Customer list or do you have just binded the grid to a DataTable (and in this case did you retrieve the primary key of that table)?

Comment: Steve, I use VB.NET 2012. I make CustomerDataset and place datagridview on form. Then automatically creates tableAdapter, bindingsource. Now I place customer details on form and also creates tableAdapter, bining source. (all this on single form) if I click Customer name on DGV1 then DGV2 show details for that customer. All this work fine. But now......... I want to move DGV2 to form2. Then if double-click on customer name in DGV1, form1 ....then form2 must open and show details for that customer..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one I think this the one that your looking for,

```
'This code below will hold the Value from your table 
Dim CustomerName as String
'This code below will hold the value of the selected row in DGV1
Dim SelectedName As Integer
SelectedName = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
```

Now here is what you do lets say the customers name is in Column1 now we will get that value like this.

```
CustomerName = DataGridView.Item(1, i).Value
```

So what happens everytime you select a data in column1 the value of that selected row goes to the `CustomerName`.

What is next you will do is create a Form2 add the Datagridview and in your code run this one.

```
Form2.Show
'Create your own way of display data in datagridview but this time your where clause is like this (where ColumName = '" & CustomerName  & "')
```

Regards

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you much for you reply. I understand the first part  - it is to determine what value is click.. To get value. So now this value must transport to form2. Please excuse I have not good English and also not know much about programming...

Comment: Then on form2.... this value must use to some filter function? I not understand form2 how to filter now only.. Say I copy CustomerID in form1.. now I want filter that in form2. Say customerID "5" now I must filter form2 DGV2 for "5" so... I don't understand the form2 section